# namespace doesn't exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I would like to try out a code in Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition and I'm getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace 'EducationalSuite.Core' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I right click the Reference but I didn't find the "Properties" either the "EducationalSuite.Core".

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using System.Resources;

namespace EducationalSuite.Core.Plugins
{
    public delegate void RectangleItemClickedDelegate(Rectangle rect, int index);

    public partial class GeoSafariItem : Control
    {
        protected List<Rectangle> lastFlashingItems = new List<Rectangle>();
        protected int lastHeight = 0;

        private Image imageFile = null;
        protected List<Rectangle> hotspots = new List<Rectangle>();
        protected Dictionary<int, string> textItems = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        protected Dictionary<int, FileInfo> audioItems = new Dictionary<int, FileInfo>();
        protected Rectangle lastRectangle;
        protected int selectedIndex = 0;
        protected int countItemsLeft = 6;
        protected int countItemsRight = 6;
        protected int imageOffsetTop = 0;
        protected int imageOffsetBottom = 0;
        protected bool paintHotSpots = false, colorSwitch = false, paintItemLabels = false;
        protected Timer timer = new Timer();

        public event RectangleItemClickedDelegate HotspotClick;
        public event RectangleItemClickedDelegate QuestionItemClick;
        public event RectangleItemClickedDelegate QuestionItemRightClick;

        protected void OnHotspotClick(Rectangle rect, int index)
        {
            if (HotspotClick != null)
            {
                HotspotClick(this.RectangleToScreen(rect), index);
            }
        }

        protected void OnQuestionItemRightClick(Rectangle rect, int index)
        {
            if (QuestionItemRightClick != null)
            {
                QuestionItemRightClick(this.RectangleToScreen(rect), index);
            }
        }

        protected void OnQuestionItemClick(Rectangle rect, int index)
        {
            if (QuestionItemClick != null)
            {
                QuestionItemClick(this.RectangleToScreen(rect), index);
            }
        }

        public GeoSafariItem()
        {
            this.imageFile = EducationalSuite.Core.Properties.Resources.singlepixel;

            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Enabled = true;

            this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(GeoSafariItem_MouseUp);

            // Activates double buffering
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            //InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetItemText(int index, string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                if (this.textItems.ContainsKey(index)) textItems.Remove(index);
            }
            else
            {
                this.textItems[index] = text;
            }

            if (PaintItemLabels)
            {
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }


        public string GetItemText(int index)
        {
            if (this.textItems.ContainsKey(index))
            {
                return this.textItems[index];
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public void SetItemAudio(int index, FileInfo file)
        {
            if ((file == null) && !file.Exists)
            {
                if (this.audioItems.ContainsKey(index)) audioItems.Remove(index);
            }
            else
            {
                this.audioItems[index] = file;
            }
        }

        public FileInfo GetItemAudio(int index)
        {
            if (this.audioItems.ContainsKey(index))
            {
                return this.audioItems[index];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        #region Recording Regions
        bool isRecording = false;
        int recordingIndex = 0;
        Point recordTopLeft = Point.Empty;
        Point recordBottomRight = Point.Empty;
        List<Rectangle> recordedRectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

        public void StartRecording()
        {
            isRecording = true;
            recordingIndex = 0;
            selectedIndex = 0;
            recordedRectangles.Clear();
            this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(GeoSafariItemRecord_MouseUp);

            this.Invalidate();
        }

        public List<Rectangle> FinishRecording()
        {
            isRecording = false;
            this.MouseUp -= new MouseEventHandler(GeoSafariItemRecord_MouseUp);
            this.Invalidate();

            this.Hotspots.Clear();
            foreach (Rectangle r in recordedRectangles)
            {
                this.Hotspots.Add(r);
            }

            return recordedRectangles;
        }

        private void GeoSafariItemRecord_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isRecording)
            {
                Rectangle size = SizeRect;
                double ratio = (double)imageFile.Height / (double)size.Height;

                if (recordTopLeft == Point.Empty)
                {
                    recordTopLeft = new Point(
                        (int)(((double)e.Location.X - (double)size.Left) * ratio),
                        (int)(((double)e.Location.Y - (double)size.Top) * ratio)
                        );
                }
                else
                {
                    recordBottomRight = new Point(
                       (int)(((double)e.Location.X - (double)size.Left) * ratio),
                       (int)(((double)e.Location.Y - (double)size.Top) * ratio)
                       );

                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(recordTopLeft,
                        new Size(recordBottomRight.X - recordTopLeft.X, recordBottomRight.Y - recordTopLeft.Y));

                    this.recordedRectangles.Add(r);
                    recordingIndex++;
                    selectedIndex++;

                    recordTopLeft = Point.Empty;
                    recordBottomRight = Point.Empty;
                }
            }
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        #endregion

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;

            if (lastRectangle.Width > 0)
            {
                this.Invalidate(lastRectangle);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private Rectangle SizeRect
        {
            get
            {
                int rw, rh,
                cw = (this.Width - 42),
                ch = (this.Height - 2),
                ox = 21,
                oy = 1;

                rw = cw;
                rh = ch;

                double imageRatio = (double)imageFile.Width / (double)imageFile.Height;
                double controlRatio = (double)cw / (double)ch;

                if (controlRatio > imageRatio)
                {
                    rw = (int)Math.Round((double)rh * imageRatio);
                    ox += Math.Abs(rw - cw) / 2;
                }
                else if (controlRatio < imageRatio)
                {
                    rh = (int)Math.Round((double)rw / imageRatio);
                    oy += Math.Abs(rh - ch) / 2;
                }

                return new Rectangle(ox, oy, rw, rh);
            }
        }

        void GeoSafariItem_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle size = SizeRect;
            for (int i = 0; i < hotspots.Count; i++)
            {
                Rectangle hotspot = hotspots[i];
                double ratio = (double)size.Height / (double)imageFile.Height;
                Rectangle adjustedRectange = new Rectangle(
                    size.Left + (int)(hotspot.X * ratio),
                    size.Top + (int)(hotspot.Y * ratio),
                    (int)(hotspot.Width * ratio),
                    (int)(hotspot.Height * ratio));

                if (adjustedRectange.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    OnHotspotClick(hotspot, i);
                    return;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < lastFlashingItems.Count; i++)
            {
                if (lastFlashingItems[i].Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                        OnQuestionItemRightClick(lastFlashingItems[i], i);
                    else
                        OnQuestionItemClick(lastFlashingItems[i], i);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Rectangle> Hotspots
        {
            get { return hotspots; }
        }

        public Image ImageFile
        {
            get { return imageFile; }
            set
            {
                imageFile = value;
                lastFlashingItems.Clear();
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return selectedIndex; }
            set { selectedIndex = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int CountItemsLeft
        {
            get { return countItemsLeft; }
            set
            {
                countItemsLeft = value;
                lastFlashingItems.Clear();
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int CountItemsRight
        {
            get { return countItemsRight; }
            set
            {
                countItemsRight = value;
                lastFlashingItems.Clear();
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int ImageOffsetTop
        {
            get { return imageOffsetTop; }
            set
            {
                imageOffsetTop = value;
                lastFlashingItems.Clear();
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public int ImageOffsetBottom
        {
            get { return imageOffsetBottom; }
            set
            {
                imageOffsetBottom = value;
                lastFlashingItems.Clear();
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public bool PaintHotSpots
        {
            get { return paintHotSpots; }
            set { paintHotSpots = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        public bool PaintItemLabels
        {
            get { return paintItemLabels; }
            set { paintItemLabels = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

            string itemText;
            SizeF sizeItemText;
            double topOffset = imageOffsetTop;
            double bottomOffset = imageOffsetBottom;
            double topOffsetPct = (double)topOffset / (double)imageFile.Height;
            double bottomOffsetPct = (double)bottomOffset / (double)imageFile.Height;

            Rectangle size = SizeRect;

            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            g.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Ivory, size.X - 25, size.Y, size.Width + 50, size.Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkKhaki, size.X - 25, size.Y - 1, size.Width + 50, size.Height + 1);
            g.DrawImage(imageFile, size.X, size.Y, size.Width, size.Height);


            Rectangle rect, rectItemText;
            Brush selectedColor = (colorSwitch ? Brushes.Crimson : Brushes.Red);
            topOffset = topOffsetPct * size.Height;
            bottomOffset = bottomOffsetPct * size.Height;
            int tmpHeight = (size.Height - (int)topOffset - (int)bottomOffset) / countItemsLeft;
            if (size.Height != this.lastHeight || this.lastFlashingItems.Count == 0)
            {
                lastHeight = size.Height;
                lastFlashingItems.Clear();

                int actualIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < countItemsLeft; i++)
                {
                    int yy = size.Y + (tmpHeight * i) + (int)topOffset;
                    int xx = size.X - 18;
                    rect = new Rectangle(xx, yy, 16, 8);
                    this.lastFlashingItems.Add(rect);

                    g.FillRectangle((actualIndex == selectedIndex ? selectedColor : Brushes.Khaki), rect);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkKhaki, rect);

                    if (actualIndex == selectedIndex)
                    {
                        lastRectangle = rect;
                    }

                    itemText = this.GetItemText(actualIndex);
                    if (PaintItemLabels && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemText))
                    {
                        // Draw Text next to each notch
                        sizeItemText = g.MeasureString(itemText, this.Font);

                        int xxx = size.X + 10;
                        rectItemText = new Rectangle(xxx, yy, Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Width), Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Height));
                        PaintHotspot(g, Color.White, rectItemText, 200);

                        g.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)xxx, (float)yy);
                    }

                    actualIndex++;
                }

                tmpHeight = (size.Height - (int)topOffset - (int)bottomOffset) / countItemsRight;
                for (int i = 0; i < countItemsRight; i++)
                {
                    int yy = size.Y + (tmpHeight * i) + (int)topOffset;
                    int xx = size.X + size.Width + 2;
                    rect = new Rectangle(xx, yy, 16, 8);
                    this.lastFlashingItems.Add(rect);

                    g.FillRectangle((actualIndex == selectedIndex ? selectedColor : Brushes.Khaki), rect);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkKhaki, rect);

                    if (actualIndex == selectedIndex)
                    {
                        lastRectangle = rect;
                    }

                    itemText = this.GetItemText(actualIndex);
                    if (PaintItemLabels && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemText))
                    {
                        // Draw Text next to each notch
                        sizeItemText = g.MeasureString(itemText, this.Font);

                        int xxx = size.X + size.Width - 10 - Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Width);
                        rectItemText = new Rectangle(xxx, yy, Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Width), Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Height));
                        PaintHotspot(g, Color.White, rectItemText, 200);

                        g.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)xxx, (float)yy);
                    }
                    actualIndex++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lastHeight = size.Height;
                for (int i = 0; i < lastFlashingItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle((i == selectedIndex ? selectedColor : Brushes.Khaki), lastFlashingItems[i]);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkKhaki, lastFlashingItems[i]);

                    if (i == selectedIndex)
                    {
                        lastRectangle = lastFlashingItems[i];
                    }
                }

                if (PaintItemLabels)
                {
                    int actualIndex = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < countItemsLeft; i++)
                    {
                        itemText = this.GetItemText(actualIndex);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemText))
                        {
                            int yy = size.Y + (tmpHeight * i) + (int)topOffset;
                            // Draw Text next to each notch
                            sizeItemText = g.MeasureString(itemText, this.Font);

                            int xxx = size.X + 10;
                            rectItemText = new Rectangle(xxx, yy, Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Width), Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Height));
                            PaintHotspot(g, Color.White, rectItemText, 200);

                            g.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)xxx, (float)yy);
                        }

                        actualIndex++;
                    }

                    tmpHeight = (size.Height - (int)topOffset - (int)bottomOffset) / countItemsRight;
                    for (int i = 0; i < countItemsRight; i++)
                    {
                        itemText = this.GetItemText(actualIndex);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemText))
                        {
                            int yy = size.Y + (tmpHeight * i) + (int)topOffset;
                            // Draw Text next to each notch
                            sizeItemText = g.MeasureString(itemText, this.Font);

                            int xxx = size.X + size.Width - 10 - Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Width);
                            rectItemText = new Rectangle(xxx, yy, Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Width), Convert.ToInt32(sizeItemText.Height));
                            PaintHotspot(g, Color.White, rectItemText, 200);

                            g.DrawString(itemText, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)xxx, (float)yy);
                        }
                        actualIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Calling the base class OnPaint
            base.OnPaint(pe);

            if (this.isRecording)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.recordedRectangles.Count; i++)
                {
                    rect = recordedRectangles[i];
                    double ratio = (double)size.Height / (double)imageFile.Height;
                    Rectangle adjustedRectange = new Rectangle(
                        size.Left + (int)(rect.X * ratio),
                        size.Top + (int)(rect.Y * ratio),
                        (int)(rect.Width * ratio),
                        (int)(rect.Height * ratio));

                    PaintHotspot(g, Color.LightBlue, adjustedRectange, (i + 1).ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (this.paintHotSpots)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < hotspots.Count; i++)
                {
                    Rectangle hotspot = hotspots[i];
                    double ratio = (double)size.Height / (double)imageFile.Height;
                    Rectangle adjustedRectange = new Rectangle(
                        size.Left + (int)(hotspot.X * ratio),
                        size.Top + (int)(hotspot.Y * ratio),
                        (int)(hotspot.Width * ratio),
                        (int)(hotspot.Height * ratio));

                    PaintHotspot(g, Color.LightGreen, adjustedRectange, (i + 1).ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void PaintHotspot(Graphics g, Color c, Rectangle hotspot, int alpha)
        {
            PaintHotspot(g, c, hotspot, alpha, null);
        }

        protected virtual void PaintHotspot(Graphics g, Color c, Rectangle hotspot, string txt)
        {
            PaintHotspot(g, c, hotspot, 100, txt);
        }

        protected virtual void PaintHotspot(Graphics g, Color c, Rectangle hotspot, int alpha, string txt)
        {
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, c));
            g.FillRectangle(brush, hotspot);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
                g.DrawString(txt, this.Font, Brushes.DarkGreen, hotspot.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

I imagine the following line is causing the error.

```
this.imageFile = EducationalSuite.Core.Properties.Resources.singlepixel;
```

The code is referring to a image resource "singlepixel". This image must be in the default resource file of the EducationalSuite.Core assembly. First confirm that you are currently editing the said assembly by opening Project Properties and checking the Default Namespace on the Application page. This should state "EducationalSuite.Core". If this isn't the case, you are most likely missing a reference to the said assembly.

If you have the EducationalSuite.Core project open the easiest way to add the singlepixel resource is to open project properties, Resources tab and creating a new default resource file. From the top open the Add Resource drop down and select existing file or new image depending on whether you have the file already or if you need to create it. Name the resource "singlepixel".

Visual Studio will generate Resources helper class under Properties namespace for you so you can access the resource through the Properties.Resources.singlepixel under EducationalSuite.Core in your code.

**Old answer**

In general Properties namespace is the namespace which contains application or user specific settings. You can add these settings (and the namespace) by navigating to the Settings tab in the Properties of the project.

Unfortunately it's kind of hard to say more based on this information. Could you provide the piece of code that causes this error?

If you double click the error message the IDE will take you to the line which is causing the error.

Most likely the piece of code is expecting a setting variable which is not added to the project.

Comment: hi Mikko i would like to try this one.But when I right click on my project,& select properties,I'm getting these:Application,Build,Build events,Debug,Resources,Services,Settings,Reference Path,Signing,Security,Publish on the left side. I'm not sure if I'm on the write track here.

Comment: You're on the right track. The Settings tab is the one I am referring to. But before anyone can confirm that the problem really is caused by this, you need to provide the piece of code which causes the problem. If the source code is not too long, you could edit it to the original question.

Comment: Hi Mikko, thanks for your explanation.I just would like to try out the "isRecording" here and how does it work.This code doesn't belong to me.So I don't know where to find the missing files here.I also don't have the EducationalSuite.Core project.Maybe I should look for another example.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing the Reference. If it is not under References in solution explorer than I would do a file search in windows for "EducationalSuite.Core" to see where it is on the system and add it. You may also be missing the "using" statement? If you hover over the "Properties" text you should get a small drop down that will add the using's for you.

If this does not help, more information would be helpful?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Madd,what do you mean do a file search in windows? Shall I search it in my C:\Windows\System?

Comment: oh by the way,when  hover over the "Properties", I still get the same error: The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace 'EducationalSuite.Core' (are you missing an assembly reference?)